# Changing the columns names in ASP.NET Identity 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

how can i change the name of the columns in ASP.NET Identity 2?
The default ones for the `User` table are listed below.

[image: identity 2 user table]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this easily by overriding the **OnModelCreating** in your **DbContext** then add the following to it:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    //here the magic happens :)
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
                .ToTable("Users", "dbo")
                .Property(p => p.Email)
                .HasColumnName("Email_Address");
}
```

hope it helped :)